# How did the Mogadorians know that Sandor was Nine's Cepan?

Tags: lorien-legacies

In Nine's Legacy, Sandor gets caught by the Mogs, and they torture him to get information out of Nine. But how did they know that he was Nine's Cepan? They caught him because he was "poking around" at the They Walk Among Us magazine, but he could have been any of the Cepans.

Answer (score 1):

I think because

- Cepan of number 1, 2, 3 killed along with the Garde
- Cepan of number 6 die too
- Cepan of number 8 die in India
- Cepan of number 5 already dead when they found him

=> They know for sure 6 Cepan of which number have die so when they find Sandor, they though him either Cepan of 4 or 7 or 9, and since the Cepan not go around carry the chest without his/her Garde the Mog can assume he is 9's Cepan
Beside, all Loric Chest have Loric symbol on it (can't confirm if it contain number of each Garde or not) so it maybe a good lead

Comment: 2's Cepan went separately from their Garde. Besides, how would the Mogs know what Cepan did? They had very limited knowledge, and every Cepan set up a different system.

Comment: one thing for sure the Mog know about the chest and how it important to the Garde (in The Rise of Nine, 8 say one Mog have his chest and run away without try to capture him - same with 4 when he in Sam's backyard to retrive the table) so when a Cepan go around with the chest and without the Garde - the Mog know something not right and they can assume that was 9'Cepan (the chest must always be with the Garde - or the Garde know where it hidden in order if the Cepan die, the Garde still know where the chest is and can open it)